# Tell Django's model to use as primary key a set of foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have `Person`s and `Proposal`s. Now I want to store the `Person's` votes on `Proposals`. To do so, I'll create another class which will provide an "intermediary" table. The goal is to link a `Person` with a `Proposal` and associate a vote `direction` (upvote or downvote). Code below:

```
class Persons(models.Model):
   #code
class Proposal(models.Model):
   #code
class Vote(models.Model):
    """A Person (who) votes up or down (direction) a Proposal (what)."""
    who = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    what = models.ForeignKey(Proposal)
    direction = models.BooleanField()   # true = upvote = vote in favor
```

I wanted the PrimaryKey of Vote to be (who, what) together. Instead, Django created a table with an default `AUTO-INCREMENTED id` as PrimaryKey. **How can I set a ForeignKey (or a set of ForeignKeys) as PrimaryKey?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django ORM does not support composite primary keys: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys

Comment: Should I enforce it using SQL commands? That is, execute `syncdb` to create the database and then run a set of SQL commands to delete the default `id` key and make the other two ForeignKeys my PrimaryKey. What do you think?

Comment: You'd have to, as there's no way Django ORM will do it for you. My suggestion would be to use SQLAlchemy instead of Django ORM.

Comment: Just one more question: Does Django support the promotion of **one** ForeignKey to PrimaryKey? If so, how?

Comment: Hmm. You could probably use South to do so, if you're looking for a programmatic solution, although I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @DiAlex: You can designate a field to be a primary key (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#primary-key), but only _one_ may be a primary key.

Comment: @mipadi that's for models.Fields I don't know if i can use it with models.ForeignKey, but I'll give it a try

Comment: I see what you're asking now, to which the answer is "no"

Comment: @DiAlex: A ForeignKey is a Field. :)

Answer (score 4):

I too had a similar problem and i was able to work around it by using unique_together meta (in your case under class Vote). read more about unique_together at

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately you may be stuck using **SQLAlchemy** since the standard ORM is not capable of this.